# mongodb aggregation to flatten recursive child documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation

using mongodb and the following document.

```json
{
  "_id": "7741cca6-31d4-4652-aa00-a7d547a16a2e",
  "kids": [
    {
      "_id": "e6c2f07e-899f-40b5-8ac2-9a587f26d67e",
      "kids": [
        {
          "_id": "e9b35574-add7-490e-ab9d-9b2d425bebf6",
          "kids": [
            {
              "_id": "25f6e89d-6f77-4a7f-948b-77488578710f"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to create an aggregation that will unfold the 'kids" into a document that is only one level deep like the following:

```json
{
    "_id": "7741cca6-31d4-4652-aa00-a7d547a16a2e",
    "kids": [
        {
            "_id": "e6c2f07e-899f-40b5-8ac2-9a587f26d67e"
        },
        {
            "_id": "e9b35574-add7-490e-ab9d-9b2d425bebf6"
        },
        {
            "_id": "25f6e89d-6f77-4a7f-948b-77488578710f"
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I do this?

I've tried using $project, $lookup, $unwind, $reduce, but just can't seem to get this to work.  I can do it with a java script query and recursive function, but I would like this to eventually be a view.

This is as close as I have come, but the final document added is an array in an array instead of a document in an array.

```json
[
  {
    $addFields:
      /**
       * newField: The new field name.
       * expression: The new field expression.
       */
      {
        newKids: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$kids.kids.kids",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$value",
                "$$this",
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      },
  },
  {
    $addFields:
      /**
       * newField: The new field name.
       * expression: The new field expression.
       */
      {
        newKids: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$kids.kids",
            initialValue: "$newKids",
            in: {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$value",
                "$$this",
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      },
  },
  {
    $addFields:
      /**
       * newField: The new field name.
       * expression: The new field expression.
       */
      {
        newKids: {
          $reduce: {
            input: ["$kids"],
            initialValue: "$newKids",
            in: {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$value",
                "$$this",
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      },
  },
]
```

Comment: I would say using javascript/application-level processing to flatten it would be your best bet if you have an uncertain level of recursion. Flattening the schema would be better in long-term in my opinion as you can avoid bloated documents and unnecessary complexity in queries.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no JavaScript wizard, but if JavaScript is enabled on the MongoDB server, you could implement recursive descent using `"$function"`.

N.B.:  There may be better ways to implement this.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "kids": {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function drill(kids, out) {if (kids.length > 0) {for (let elem of kids) {out.push({_id: elem._id}); drill(elem.kids??[], out)}}; return out};",
          "args": [ "$kids", [] ],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Output using your sample document:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "7741cca6-31d4-4652-aa00-a7d547a16a2e",
    "kids": [
      {
        "_id": "e6c2f07e-899f-40b5-8ac2-9a587f26d67e"
      },
      {
        "_id": "e9b35574-add7-490e-ab9d-9b2d425bebf6"
      },
      {
        "_id": "25f6e89d-6f77-4a7f-948b-77488578710f"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b5pcbeNW7XZ).

Comment: Thanks, that happens to be how I did end up handling it.  Currently they do allow JS, but not sure if that will continue, but an issue for another day.